# Enabling Host OS and Virtual OS Communicate with each other

Tags: networking, virtualbox

I have been grappling with the issue of a lack of communication between the Host OS (Windows 7) and Ubuntu 64 (Virtual Machine).

```
Current Virtual Box settings;-
   NETWORK:-  Adapter 1: Bridged Adapter
              Adapter 2: Host only Adapter

   Firewalls: Windows 7: Disabled
              Ubuntu   : Disabled
```

I can only see Virtual Box Host-only Network Connection because I deleted the Bridged Network connection hoping it would get created again but it hasn't so far. But even when I could see a Bridged Connection earlier I still could not have the ping from the host. I have rebooted several times to no avail. I am connecting to my corporate network through VPN. However I do see the 2 IP addresses in the VM though but I can't ping from either side.

Something does not add up and I would be very grateful if someone could help me connect the VM to a server in the cloud.