# Virtual Ubuntu 18.04 running on Windows 10 with VirtualBox Manager connection volume-limited

Tags: 18.04, windows, virtualbox-networking

Although my Windows 10 machine has stable and fast internet connection, the Ubuntu 18.04 machine running virtually cannot sustain a connection. A stupid Ubuntu trick I can do is to attempt to download gnome-control-center (because, why not).  **Sudo apt install gnome-control-center**.  I get lots of conversation, but when it comes time to download the app, I get error 101: Network is unreachable.  I can then immediately successfully ping banjo.cononical.com or in case anyone is wondering 91.189.91.38.

I have tried explicitly setting DNS servers, and disabling IPv6 addressing, but since I can successfully ping just about anything, I am thinking this does not address the issue.

Running lshw – C network as superuser provided a lot of info on the interface.
**lshw -C**

```
       *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface

       product: 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:03.0
       logical name: enp0s3
       version: 02
       serial: 08:00:27:a8:3c:94
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 66MHz
       capabilities: pm pcix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation

       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000 driverversion=7.3.21-k8-NAPI duplex=full ip=192.168.0.100 latency=64 link=yes mingnt=255 multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s

       resources: irq:19 memory:f1200000-f121ffff ioport:d020(size=8)
```

**dhclient enp0s3 -v**

> Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5 Copyright 2004-2016
>   Internet Systems Consortium. All rights reserved. For info, please
>   visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
>
> Listening on LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:a8:3c:94
>   Sending on LPF/enp0s3/08:00:27:a8:3c:94
>   Sending on Socket/fallback DHCPDISCOVER
>   on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0x6af07523)
>   DHCPREQUEST of 192.168.0.100 on enp0s3 to 255.255.255.255 port 67
>   (xid=0x2375f06a) DHCPOFFER of 192.168.0.100 from 192.168.0.1 DHCPACK
>   of 192.168.0.100 from 192.168.0.1 RTNETLINK answers: File exists cmp:
>   EOF on /tmp/tmp.SwCSrBB9bO which is empty bound to 192.168.0.100 --
>   renewal in 290507 seconds.

**As requested, Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager Network settings:**
Adapter 1 (enabled)
Attached to: Bridged Adapter
Name: Intel(R) Wireless AC 9260 160MHz

Adapter Type: Intel PRO/1000MT Desktop (82540EM)
Promiscuous Mode: Deny
Cable Connected

Given that Bridged Adapter is used, the Windows IP Configuration is probably of interest.  It follows, (skipping 'connections' that are disconnected):

```
>**ipconfig**

Windows IP Configuration

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.56.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Wireless LAN adapter Wi-Fi:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.128
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.0.1
```

Comment: Settings added.  Thank you for your interest, user535733.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is related to the VPN connection issues a lot of people have posted about (e.g. [using apt-get](https://askubuntu.com/questions/336870/i-cannot-use-apt-get-update) and [connecting and pinging](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1060120/enabling-host-os-and-virtual-os-communicate-with-each-other)), only in my case, when I tried connecting with VPN active it magically worked. Why, who knows, but if you are having connection issues, it might be instructive to compare short connection requests (like pings) to long connection requests (like software updates)